# Mark a portion of a bar chart ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data for number of cars sold each year for different brands like this:

[image]

But I also have data for how many of the cars sold were cars with a diesel engine for each one of the brands and years.

I want to be able to stack the charts in a bar chart and also add a second dimension to each class, showing how many of the cars that have a diesel engine of the specific brand (e.g. BMW). I want to do it either by colour, or by lines like below:

[image]

Is it possible to do that with `ggplot` in R?

Edit:
My data:

The data looks like this in Excel:

```
        BMW  Volvo  Audi
2010    50   400    50
2011    75   450    35
2012    45   350    55

        BMW         Volvo   Audi
2010    0.2         0.2     0.5
2011    0.293333333 0.5     0.571428571
2012    0.488888889 0.5     0.272727273
```

Comment: Could you add some data and maybe some attempts you made?It could be helpful to help you.

Comment: Yes, it is possible (provably using alpha instead of lines), can you add example of your data using `dput`?

Comment: I added the data in the example above.

Comment: Can you add data that you have in R? What those datasets mean? What's the difference between them?

Comment: The second one is the proportions of diesel engines and the first one is the cars. I'll add the R data once I am back at my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do a bit of data preparation to make it easier to plot, but once you do this type of thing a few times, it becomes quite straightforward.  I highly recommend reading about [Tidy Data Principles](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html), which I'll apply here.

#### Data

In the future, please post your dataframes via the output of `dput(data.frame)`, but your tables are small, so import isn't that difficult:

```
df1 <- data.frame(year=c(2010:2012), BMW=c(50,75,45), Volvo=c(400,450,350), Audi=c(50,35,55))
df2 <- data.frame(year=c(2010:2012), BMW=c(0.2, 0.29333333, 0.4888888), Volvo=c(0.2,0.5,0.5), Audi=c(0.5,0.571428571,0.2727272727272))
```

Your data should be converted into *Tidy Data*, in which the key principle is that each row is an observation, each variable is one column, and each value represents the value for that column for that observation.  Consider your first table, where you have only 3 pieces of information (variables) that are changing:  Year, Model, and number of cars sold.  As such, we need to combine those three columns for BMW, Volvo, and Audi into two: one for Model and one for number sold.  You can do that by using `gather()` from `dplyr` (or a few other ways).  Similarly, we need to combine columns in the second dataset.

Then, you can merge the two datasets together.  Then finally, I use the information from total sold * proportion which are diesel to identify the number of diesel vs. number that are not diesel.  In this way, we create the final dataframe used for plotting:

```
df1.1 <- df1 %>% gather(key='Model', value='Total_Sold',-year)
df2.1 <- df2 %>% gather(key='Model', value='prop_diesel',-year)
df <- merge(df1.1, df2.1)
df$diesel <- df$Total_Sold * df$prop_diesel
df$non_diesel <- df$Total_Sold - df$diesel
df <- df %>% gather(key='type', value='sold', -(1:4))
```

#### Plot

To create the plot, it seems like the best way to show this would be in a column plot, stacking "non-diesel" and "diesel" on top of one another so you can see total amount compared across each make per year, which also estimating the proportion of diesel/non-diesel.  We kind of want to use dodging (separating columns out for make where they share the same x axis value), as well as "stacking" (stacking info on diesel vs. non-diesel).  You kind of can't do that at the same time for a column plot, but I'm using faceting to get the same effect.  Here you assign Model as the x axis, use stacking for the amount sold, and then faceting to create the subsets per year.  Here's the code and result:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Model, y=sold)) +
    geom_col(aes(fill=type), position='stack') +
    facet_wrap(~year)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That is a very nice solution indeed. Would it however be possible to dot a part of the chart as I tried to do in paint above if I really wanted?

Comment: Not with a patterned fill - that's not supported with ggplot and basically any solution I've seen is a wonky workaround with mediocre results.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Then I suppose your solution is the best available.

Comment: I stand corrected... you may be able to use `ggpattern` to make a patterned fill ([see page here](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/2020/04/01/introducing-ggpattern-pattern-fills-for-ggplot/)).  However, to do what you drew is like a stacked plot with pattern-stacking.  Probably not impossible, but I think there are better ways to show that kind of data.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot! That might come handy if I have to do black and white graphs.

Comment: Seems the package is quite new - did not know that one existed, but glad it does now, since it is something that I've seen asked here on SO a number of times.